# Call hierarchy does not work on class names or variables Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Ctrl + alt + h   ,call hierarchy works on methods and constructors but does not work for class names and variables unlike eclipse.

Is there any workaround available ?

I searched alot but did not find any solution

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALT + F7` will show the usage of classes and variables.

Comment: But that does not actually give you the entire usage **hierarchy** of classes and variables, which is what the question is asking for. It only gives you one level of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 added [support for showing the call hierarchy for fields.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160274)

Android Studio 3.6.3 uses improvements through IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4, so `call hierarchy for fields` is not yet available in Android Studio.